# Phase 1 and Phase 2 initialization in Swift

Tags: swift, initialization

This is copy from Apple Swift documentation:

> As soon as all properties of the superclass have an initial value,
>   its memory is considered fully initialized, and Phase 1 is complete.
>
> The superclass’s designated initializer now has an opportunity to
>   customize the instance further (although it does not have to).
>
> Once the superclass’s designated initializer is finished, the
>   subclass’s designated initializer can perform additional customization
>   (although again, it does not have to).

So basically the Phase 1 makes sure that all properties have a value and assigns that value to them. In Phase 2 these properties are further customized. And that further customization really frustrates me because I can't think of a single example in which further customazation is used. Can you give me a simple example of this initialization behaviour or provide additional explanation of Phase 1 and 2? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given 2 classes Foo and Bar where Bar is a subclass of Foo:

```
class Foo {
    var a: Int?
    var b: Int?

    init() {
        a = 1
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    var c: Int?

    override init() {
        super.init() // Phase 1

        // Phase 2: Additional customizations
        b = 2
        c = 3
    }
}
```

When you call `Bar()` it calls `super.init()` which the first line is to initialize the superclass which is Foo. So once Foo's properties are initialized completely, they can be set in Foo's initializer. This is represented by the `a = 1` in the Foo initializer.

Once that is complete, phase 2 begins which is continuing the initialization of Bar following the `super.init()` line. This is where you can "perform additional customizations" either on the instance of bar or on its superclass. This is represented by `b = 2` and `c = 3`.

```
let x = Bar()
x.a // 1
x.b // 2
x.c // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Example you want an `UIView` which is always red. self.frame is set in Phase 1 (by calling `[super initWithFrame:frame]`, you change `self.backgroundColor` in you implementation of `initWithFrame:`, that's Phase 2.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame]; <- Phase 1

    if (self) {
        //Phase 2
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

---

Sorry for the Objective-C code, but it should be pretty much the same in Siwft, just with different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. Phase 1 is quite limited. **All** it does is set all required property values. You can't do anything else until that's done.

In phase 1, you can't refer to self, and you can't call other methods. That's very limiting.

Once phase 1 is complete, you are free to call other methods and to refer to self.

Most of what you think of as code that takes place in an init method takes place in phase 2.

If you have an object that manages a network connection, it would need to set up that network connection in phase 2, for example.

Answer (score 1):

My example to understand First Phase and Second Phase in Swift Innitialization .

```
class A {
  var a: Int
  var b: Int
  init() {
     // This is phare 1
     a = 1
     b = 2
  }
}

 class B: A {
   var c: Character
   var d: Double
   var e: String
   overide init() {
      // This is phare 1
      c = ""
      d = 0.0
      e = ""
      This is Phase 2
      d = 10
      e = "abc"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Phase 1:** Starts from sub to super class, alloc memory and init property 
**Phase 2:** Continue from super to sub class, customisation

[image]