# Gesture recognizer not working if created at class init time

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

In a collection view, I create a gesture recognizer at class init time. In the `viewDidLoad` method, I then add the gesture recognizer to the collection view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongGesture(gesture:)))

    @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        // some code
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }
}
```

With this, the gesture recognizer does not work.

The fix is easy: it suffices to move the line with `let longPressGesture` to the `viewDidLoad` method and everything works as expected. However, I find it a bit surprising that the first version would not work.

Can anyone explain why the first version is not working? Is it because, when the gesture recognizer is created, the collection view is not yet ready to have gestures? So, what must a gesture recognizer know about its target in order to be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. That's because you are trying to use `self` when not fully initialized.

Now, how to make that work with the way you wanted? Perhaps declare it *lazily*, like so:

```
private lazy var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer! = {
    let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
    return gesture
}()
```

Edit: Quoting giorashc's answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31021592/3231194):

> Due to swift's 2-phase initialization you need to initialize the
>   parent class before you can use self in the inheriting class.
>
> In your implementation self is yet to be initialized by the parent
>   class so as you said you should move it to the init method of your
>   view controller and create the button after calling the parent's
>   initialization method

[2 Phase Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230467/phase-1-and-phase-2-initialization-in-swift) SO Question & Answer.

Comment: Indeed a lazy declaration would work. You could simply take my declaration and replace `let` with `lazy var`, with no need for a code block. However, my question was about the precise reason why the initial attempt did not work. I'm aware that `self` may not be fully initialized, but what is it that the gesture recognizer is missing at that point (`self` as a pointer should be defined, and if not, we shouldn't be allowed using it by the compiler)? If it's about the extent of the view it should handle, well, the geometry is not yet set even at the level of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: See my again my answer. I hope I added the correct explanation.

Comment: No doubt that is the right explanation (which I'll accept). However, this triggers one question: why does the compiler allow us to use `self` there if `self` is not ready to be used? As you know, we can't directly inspect the type of self with alt+click in XCode. However, by writing `let test = self` and alt-clicking on `test` I found out to my surprise that the type of `self` is not `ViewController` but `(ViewController) -> () -> ViewController` (i.e., a closure that takes a `ViewController` and returns a closure that takes nothing and returns a `ViewController`). Now I'm a little confused...

Comment: Sorry if I can't further answer your question, I think I can but I'm afraid that I'd give you the wrong info. Perhaps Apple's documentation has the answer for such follow up question of yours. Or better yet, open that up as a new question. That's interesting to me though, and I'd like to know the correct answer. :D Coz what I have in mind is most probably incorrect.

Comment: I accepted your answer and posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797017/the-type-of-self-in-swift-and-its-use-with-respect-to-two-phase-initialization