# The type of self in Swift and its use with respect to two-phase initialization

Tags: swift, initialization, self

Consider the following code, which adds a gesture recognizer to a view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture(gesture:)))
    let test1 = self

    @objc func handleGesture(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // some code
        print("hello")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let test2 = self
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}
```

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684641/gesture-recognizer-not-working-if-created-at-class-init-time), the above code does not work because I'm trying to use `self` (in the gesture recognizer's initializer) when not fully initialized, and this is so because of Swift's two-phase initialization.

I'm not interested in the easy fix to make this work, but this triggers a couple of questions:

1) Why does the compiler allow us to use `self` here if `self` is not ready to be used? Shouldn't I get a compiler error if I'm trying to use `self` too soon?

2) We can't directly inspect the type of `self` with alt+click in XCode. However, we can inspect the types of my ad hoc variables `test1` and `test2`. While `test2`'s type is `ViewController`, as expected, `test1`'s type is `(ViewController) -> () -> ViewController` (i.e., a closure that takes a `ViewController` and returns a closure that takes nothing and returns a `ViewController`). What is that and why does `self` have two different types within the same class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1)

***Shouldn't I get a compiler error if I'm trying to use `self` too soon?***

I do agree. You may send a [bug report to swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/).

***Why does the compiler allow us to use `self` here if `self` is not ready to be used?***

Unfortunately, there's another `self` in the descendants of `NSObject`, [the method `self()` of `NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418954-self).

2)

***What is that and why does self have two different types within the same class?***

The current Swift interprets the initial value expression in the `class` context, not in the instance context.

You know method names can be used as closures in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //..

    func aMethod() {
        //...
    }

    func anInstanceMethod() {
        let meth = aMethod // () -> ()
    }
}
```

Swift can also refer to an instance method in the `class` context, which generates a so-called unapplied method reference (see [SE-0042](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0042-flatten-method-types.md)), which currently returns a curried function:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //...

    func aMethod() {
        //...
    }

    class func aClassMethod() {
        let meth = aMethod // (ViewController) -> () -> ()
    }
}
```

The method `self()` as well.

Generally we do not need `self()` method and this behavior should be changed, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting behaviour that works for Objective-C objects. Let's take these three examples:

```
class Object: NSObject {
  let test = self // compiles
}

class NonNSObject {
//  let test = self // errors
  lazy var lazyTest = self // compiles

}

struct NonClass {
//  let test = self // errors
  lazy var lazyTest = self // errors
}
```

`NonNSObject` exhibits what you'd escape:

The object cannot reference itself until it is fully initialized, and `let` bindings must all be initialized before full initialization, so this failed.

However, NSObject happens to have an Objective-C method `- (instancetype)self;` which returns self. We can model this on NonNSObject as so:

```
func returnSelf() -> NonNSObject {
    return self
}
```

This is where we start to see the answer to 2).

If we reference this method `returnSelf` on the *Class* we get the signature `(NonNSObject) -> () -> NonNSObject`. You can do this with any instance method as so:

```
let test = NonNSObject.returnSelf
```

The signature makes sense in this context:

1. The argument is the object we actually want to call the method *on*
2. Then we "apply" the function (with no arguments, in this case)
3. And we finally get our return value

`let curriedFunction = NonNSObject.returnSelf // (Self) -> () -> Self
let readyToCall = curriedFunction(NonNSObject()) // () -> Self
let finallyApplied = readyToCall() // Self`

Putting all the pieces together, we can see that in the case of ViewController (which inherits from UIViewController which way up the chain inherits from NSObject) there is an instance method `self` which the compiler is assuming you meant, so it uses that instead of the instance itself (as that would be an error). Its signature is thus a natural consequence of using an instance method on the class itself—it needs an instance, which is the first argument.

In summary:

1) Instead of assuming you made an error, the Swift compiler finds a function `self` on NSObject and returns the curried form. 
2) This is the curried form of a function, in particular, an instance method which returns its own type. 
2.5) It's still highlighted in pink because Swift-ObjC interop is mildly hacky, and `self` is both a method and, well, `self`.

As a bonus, the struct cannot reference itself at all, even lazily.